# What to do if using Drupal 7 but host only supports Drupal 6?

Tags: 7

What to do if using Drupal 7 but host only supports Drupal 6? Downgrade not an option. Would like to keep Drupal 7.

Comment: Please explain more about the situation.  What is the "host" and why can't you upgrade it to Drupal 7?

Comment: host is https://www.webhostingph.com they can only support til Drupal 6. What can i do to fix this compatibility issue?

Comment: created a website using Drupal 7 (already paid host), not knowing that it only supports Drupal 6. Would like to keep Drupal 7...any way to fix this?

Comment: Try to get a refund, but they don't do refunds, you should consider the money already paid to hosting provider lost. Find a new hosting provider. Check that the new provider supports Drupal 7 before signing up. Since Drupal 6 is about to become obsolete, I find it strange that a hosting provider in 2014 will not support Drupal 7 (and Drupal 8), but if that's the case, just find a more up-to-date hosting provider. Only reason I can think of for not supporting Drupal 7 is that they run a really old and insecure version of PHP. You don't want to be at host like that anyway.

Comment: What it the reason Drupal 7 is not supported? That is still an unanswered question. Drupal 6 and drupal 7 are very similar in their requirements and the differences in requirements are usually easily rectified. The other possibility is that their "Softaculous Apps Marketplace" doesn't support Drupal 7, but that shouldn't stop you from manually installing your site without using their apps installer thingy. Considering the cheap price of the hosting (going by the home page) Free Radical's suggestion of cutting your losses and going somewhere else might not be a bad idea.